# What build flags are available for brew install of gcc?

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, gcc

I'm curious as to what build flags are available to me when installing `gcc 4.8` using `brew`.

[This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38222/how-do-i-install-gcc-via-homebrew) explains how to install gcc 4.8 using brew, but only specifies two possible flags i.e (`--enable-cxx` and `--enable-fortran`).

Is there a list of what's available or can someone iterate them for me?

If it matters I am running OS X 10.7.5 on the Intel i5 dual core.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `brew options`. On my machine I get this:

```
brew options gcc48
--enable-all-languages
        Enable all compilers and languages, except Ada
--enable-cxx
        Build the g++ compiler
--enable-fortran
        Build the gfortran compiler
--enable-java
        Buld the gcj compiler
--enable-multilib
        Build with multilib support
--enable-nls
        Build with native language support (localization)
--enable-objc 
        Enable Objective-C language support
--enable-objcxx
        Enable Objective-C++ language support
--enable-profiled-build
        Make use of profile guided optimization when bootstrapping GCC
```

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a direct way to list all the possible flags for different software. With `brew options [formula]` you can list the build flags you can use directly with `brew install`. These options are defined in the `Formula` of the software and you can inspect it with `brew edit [formula]` (e.g. `brew edit gcc48` and search for `option` lines).

However, at least with `gcc` (and any software that uses Autoconf), you can list *all* possible flags by following the steps below.

First, use `brew install -i gcc48` to get a shell with the package to be installed extracted to a temporary directory. From there, you can use `./configure --help` to list all possible flags for the particular software.

If you want to use some of the flags not possible with `brew`, you can proceed as you would with a normal installation without `brew` (`./configure [flags]; make; make install`). After that, when you `exit`, `brew` should pick up the finished build and you are done.

If you just `exit` after taking a look at the `./configure --help`, `brew` notices that the there is nothing to be installed and exits with an error ("Error: Empty installation"). The same happens when there is some error in the actual build process ("Aborting due to non-zero exit status").