# How to set gcc 4.8 as default gcc compiler

Tags: macos, xcode, homebrew, gcc

I recently installed `gcc 4.8` using `brew` on `OSX 10.7.5 (Lion)`. I can now compile using `gcc 4.8` by using

```
g++-4.8 some_file.c
```

or using the default `gcc 4.2` by using

```
g++ some_file.c
```

I want to use `gcc 4.8` as the default compiler for `Xcode` and if I type `gcc` at the terminal. I suppose I must alter `gcc-related` links within `dirname $(which gcc)`.

When I do

```
ls -al $(dirname $(which gcc)) | grep 'gcc\|g++\|c++'
```

I get the following:

```
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel         7 Jul 31 12:17 c++ -> clang++
-rwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel    909360 Nov 18  2011 c++filt
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel         5 Jul 31 12:17 clang++ -> clang
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        12 Jul 31 12:17 g++ -> llvm-g++-4.2
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        12 Jul 31 12:17 gcc -> llvm-gcc-4.2
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        28 Jul 31 12:17 gcov-4.2 -> ../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/gcov-4.2
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        52 Jul 31 12:17 i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 -> ../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        52 Jul 31 12:17 i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 -> ../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        32 Jul 31 12:17 llvm-cpp-4.2 -> ../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-cpp-4.2
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        32 Jul 31 12:17 llvm-g++ -> ../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-g++-4.2
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        32 Jul 31 12:17 llvm-g++-4.2 -> ../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-g++-4.2
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        32 Jul 31 12:17 llvm-gcc -> ../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        32 Jul 31 12:17 llvm-gcc-4.2 -> ../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2
```

When I run: `which gcc-4.8` I get `/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.8`.

Steps to get this done would be very helpful.

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Thanks to you all for your help. I ended up just creating aliases within `~/.bash_profile` as follows:

```
alias gcc='gcc-4.8'
alias cc='gcc-4.8'
alias g++='g++-4.8'
alias c++='c++-4.8'
```

The answer from Lynken is very helpful, but I adapted it with aliases since that's easier for me to undo if necessary.

Specifically, if `PATH` is set such that `/usr/local/bin` (where brew puts the link to `gcc 4.8`) appears before appears `/usr/bin` (where `gcc` is linked by default), then creating links as Lyken suggested within `/usr/local/bin` should theoretically work for me. In practice, it doesn't for some reason -- failing with a linker error and aliases work around that error without me needing to solve that issue, too.

The other benefit of aliases is that I'm not having to link which I want homebrew to handle and not have to compete with that tool for which version of gcc is linked in `/usr/local`

Answer (score 25):

Assuming you're using bash (it's the default), then you can add /usr/local/bin as your top priority in PATH like this:

```
echo "PATH=\"/usr/local/bin:$PATH\"" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

This will ensure that /usr/local/bin is checked before all other areas of your path. Then just start a new terminal session to load the new variable.

Another way to do this:

```
  cd /usr/bin
  rm cc gcc c++ g++
  ln -s /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.8 cc
  ln -s /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.8 gcc
  ln -s /usr/local/bin/c++-4.8 c++
  ln -s /usr/local/bin/g++-4.8 g++
```

Comment: For users on Mac os Catalina or higher, if you want to replace the symbolic links your need to do [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59395264/10797718) before replace them, and also your will need to do `sudo rm -rf` not just `rm` and `sudo ln` not simply `ln`

Comment: Finally manage to do that. I also had to run `csrutil disable` in Restart mode on Mac.

Answer (score 15):

I use to gcc-4.8:

```
export CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc

export CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++

export CPP=/usr/local/bin/cpp

export LD=/usr/local/bin/gcc

alias c++=/usr/local/bin/c++

alias g++=/usr/local/bin/g++

alias gcc=/usr/local/bin/gcc

alias cpp=/usr/local/bin/cpp

alias ld=/usr/local/bin/gcc

alias cc=/usr/local/bin/gcc
```

and back to apple gcc:

```
export CC=/usr/bin/gcc

export CXX=/usr/bin/g++

export CPP=/usr/bin/cpp

export LD=/usr/bin/ld

alias c++=/usr/bin/c++

alias g++=/usr/bin/g++

alias gcc=/usr/bin/gcc

alias cpp=/usr/bin/cpp

alias cc=/usr/bin/gcc

alias ld=/usr/bin/ld
```

or put it in file and then: `source <file>`

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. We have to append the version to the end

Answer (score 3):

On Mac M1, if you use `brew install gcc`, gcc will be installed on "/opt/homebrew/bin/".

I am facing the same issue. Specifically, when I issue `gcc --version`, the terminal shows:

```
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Further looking into this, I found that in `$PATH` the path `/opt/homebrew/bin/` was actually before `/usr/bin/`. But in the former location there is only `gcc-12` in the folder, which causes gcc points to the later location (`/usr/bin/`).

In order for the GNU gcc to be found, I used this: `ln -s gcc-12 gcc`.

Restart the terminal and it's been solved:

```
gcc --version
gcc (Homebrew GCC 12.2.0) 12.2.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume your actual shell initialization is done through `~/.profile`, then you will have to modify it so as to put `/usr/local/bin` ahead of any other PATH component where `gcc` and all its associated binary are.

Here is the way to perform this clean modification:

```
cd

_shell_init=`egrep '(^| )PATH' .profile 2>/dev/null`

if [ "${_shell_init}" = "" ] ; then
    # PATH isn't defined in .profile
    # install there the first relative definition of PATH
    echo 'PATH=/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
export PATH' >>.profile
    . .profile
    exec ${SHELL}
else
    # remove all occurences of /usr/local/bin wherever they might be
    # set into PATH, and insert it ahead of all other components
    sed -E -e '/(^| )PATH=/s,:/usr/local/bin,,' \
        -e '/(^| )PATH=/s,/usr/local/bin:,,' \
        -e '/(^| )PATH=/s,,&/usr/local/bin:,' .profile >.profile.new
    mv .profile.new .profile
    . .profile
    exec ${SHELL}
fi
```

Beware: if your `~/.profile` is already structured, this shell script will have to be manually tuned to fit correct PATH definition
in the right place.

Comment: This is certainly **perfect** for modifying `PATH` so that `/usr/local/bin` is seen first. This will likely save me headaches in the future. I wish I could +1 you. 

My issue though is that `gcc` is still linked to `gcc 4.2` and not `gcc 4.8` because there is no symlink for `gcc -> gcc-4.8` in `/usr/local/bin`. I would still need to either alias `gcc` as `gcc-4.8` within `~/.profile` or symlink (`ln -s gcc-4.8 gcc`) in `/usr/local/bin` after updating `PATH` with your script. Ye?

Comment: I'm surprised `brew` didn't add the right symbolic links. Did you read this answer on the same subject: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/38247/22003 ?