# GCC : Command not found

Tags: macos, xcode, command-line, development, gcc

I'm very new to Mac and right now my operating system is 10.10 Yosemite.
I installed XCode and Xcode CLT, gcc came along with it as well. 
I was asked to change the default compiler to gcc.
I went online to this question here to find out how to do it - 
[How to set gcc 4.8 as default gcc compiler](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99077/how-to-set-gcc-4-8-as-default-gcc-compiler)

and these were the instructions I chose to follow (They seemed pretty straightforward) -

```
cd /usr/bin

rm cc gcc c++ g++

ln -s gcc-4.8 cc

ln -s gcc-4.8 gcc

ln -s c++-4.8 c++

ln -s g++-4.8 g++
```

But the problem is that now when I type `gcc` it says Command not found. Why is that? 
When I `cd /usr/bin/` and `ls` I can see gcc, cc, g++, clang etc. 
It basically says the same message 'command not found' for these commands - `cc` `gcc` `c++` and `g++` 
(I was wondering why the instructions above mentioned to rm those 4 but this answer has been provided in multiple places so it must be correct.)

clang still works thankfully, although I still require gcc.

I also used `sudo port install gcc49` to get gcc4.9 and I assumed it would have installed it perfectly, but I still get the same gcc error. 
Can anyone give me a step wise procedure on what I should do to get gcc, cc, g++ and c++ working again?

Again - Mac newbie here. Please be kind :(

Comment: $ gcc --version

Comment: @Buscar웃 This is the output I still get -


-bash: gcc: command not found

Comment: do you need to install the command line tools ? http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/12/install-command-line-tools-mac-os-x/

Comment: I already installed it. Does the environment variable have to be added to bash manually? Not that I know how to do that either. :\

Comment: type /usr/bin/gcc and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

If your filesystem is case sensitive, then you probably meant to enter **gcc** instead of **GCC**

Comment: I apologize for the mistake in the question I posted. I used lowercase only.