# Homebrew default compiler

Tags: homebrew, gcc

I have read similar topics here, but unfortunately these solutions does not help me.

I would like to recompile all installed software (or at least some formulas) from Homebrew using `gcc` from `Homebrew`.

**Is it possible to  force `Homebrew` to use specific compiler (*e.g. `gcc`*) and compiler options (*e.g. std library to use for linking*)?**

I have tried to set all kinds of environment variables, but it does not help :/ ?

```
0/> env | grep CC
HOMEBREW_CC=gcc
CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc
0/kpykc> echo $PATH
/Users/kp/kpykc/devel/bin:/opt/ros/indigo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin
0/kpykc> ls -la /usr/local/bin/g??-?.?
lrwxr-xr-x  1 kp  admin  31 Nov 24 16:23 /usr/local/bin/g++-4.9@ -> ../Cellar/gcc/4.9.2/bin/g++-4.9
lrwxr-xr-x  1 kp  admin  31 Nov 24 16:23 /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9@ -> ../Cellar/gcc/4.9.2/bin/gcc-4.9
0/kpykc> ls -la /usr/local/bin/g[c+][c+]
lrwxr-xr-x  1 kp  admin  22 Nov 11 23:54 /usr/local/bin/g++@ -> /usr/local/bin/g++-4.9
lrwxr-xr-x  1 kp  admin  22 Nov 11 23:53 /usr/local/bin/gcc@ -> /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9
```

Also tried to use [this solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99077/how-to-set-gcc-4-8-as-default-gcc-compiler?rq=1).

The reason for doing that is that I want to compile **some code*** with gcc and link against libraries installed from brew. But it seems that gcc can't link to libs built by clang. On other side it lacks support of some C++11 features which are required by the **program*** i would like to compile.

So only solution that I see, is to recompile all needed libs with gcc.

Thank you for help.

Update (on system/compiler/homebrew versions):

```
0/kpykc> sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.10.1
BuildVersion:   14B25
0/kpykc> brew config
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.5
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew
HEAD: 32923f435c7cf93820f434d6bdacf3bfdc3695eb
Last commit: 11 days ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
CPU: quad-core 64-bit ivybridge
OS X: 10.10.1-x86_64
CLT: 6.1.1.0.1.1416017670
Clang: 6.0 build 600
X11: 2.7.7 => /opt/X11
System Ruby: 2.0.0-481
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /usr/local/bin/python => /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks /Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
Ruby: /usr/bin/ruby
```

In particular I have troubles with code which uses `Eigen::aligned_allocator`.
I have updated `Eigen` to `HEAD` version from `Homebrew`.
I suspect my problem is also connected with [this bug](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=503). But it should be fixed in `HEAD`, I think so.

Comment: Which OS - note the issue is not necessarily the compiler but the C++ std library you link with - also which programs have this issue clang now has good C++11 features

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, anyway this adds to question "how to force homebrew use specific compiler and compiler options, e.g. std library to use"