# Installed gcc with Homebrew, now how to use that gcc instead of clang?

Tags: homebrew, gcc

I installed gcc with `brew install gcc`, but when I type `gcc` the default behavior is still to use `clang`.  How do I set things so that typing `gcc` in the terminal automatically uses the `gcc` installed by Homebrew?

Comment: I have gone through this issue and worked for me was this link below. The answer from **Mark Setchell** was the best for this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28970935/osx-replace-gcc-version-4-2-1-with-4-9-installed-via-homebrew/28982564#28982564

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First, examine your $PATH variable.

```
echo $PATH
```

The `gcc` from homebrew should be a symbolic link that resides in `/usr/local/bin` for [Intel and Rosetta 2 installs](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ) or `/opt/homebrew/bin` for Apple Silicon. When this brewed version of `gcc` shows up in the path listed before the Xcode version of `gcc`/`clang`, you’re done - the local compilers will be called unless a package is hard coded to the full path of a different compiler than the one you have in `/usr/local`

If you change the PATH variable - be sure to log out of the shell or [rehash the shell](https://superuser.com/questions/490983/how-to-rehash-executables-in-path-with-bash) as appropriate.

[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/99157/5472) has an elegant solution using aliases as well - so you don't even have to think or care about path if you have more than one `gcc` installed. It goes deeper to let you choose which version of gcc to call if you happen to install more than one version.

Comment: Putting the homebrew gcc earlier in the $PATH variable than the Xcode version is sufficient to guarantee that the homebrew gcc will be referenced?  I wasn't sure how double definitions in $PATH would work.

Comment: Paths are order dependent. Putting /usr/local ahead of /usr is a standard way to override the default application. I've seen people put a ~/bin ahead of that.

Comment: Homebrew does not put `gcc` in `/usr/local/bin`. This is for compatibility as everything would then use `gcc` instead of the system `clang` compiler (which is also aliased as `gcc`). What it does do is put a versioned link in `/usr/local/bin` such as `gcc-8`.

Comment: “Everything” is a bit of an overstatement; only things that explicitly call “gcc” _and_ actually depend on “gcc” _not_ referring to `gcc` but to `clang`.  (Such code should instead call either “clang” or perhaps “cc”.)  The quantity of such broken code perhaps justifies this bit of trickery.  (I am _not_ speaking officially for whoever my employer might have been when this decision was made, which I didn’t like.)

Comment: Why do we assume brew installation of gcc is in `/usr/local/bin`?  When I do `which gcc` I don't get the newest version that brew installed.  `/usr/local/bin/gcc --version` gives `gcc (Homebrew GCC 10.2.0_4) 10.2.0` and this is just clang wrapper, but the version linked by brew should be `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/bin/gcc-<version>` and  `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/bin/g++-<version>`

Comment: Thanks @BrianWiley - I’ve updates this for the Apple Silicon guidance from the FAQ as well as call out that a link named `gcc` is what matters for the $PATH variable. You are correct that non standard installs are possible and based on versions the link may point at several eventual cellar locations.

Answer (score 14):

If `which gcc` gives you

```
> which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

You have two options:

1. [Create an alias](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/99157/5472).
2. Make a new `gcc` symlink under `/usr/local/bin/`.

   Homebrew links own gcc under `/usr/local/bin/gcc-<version>` for
   compatibility. So, doing

   `ln -sf /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9 /usr/local/bin/gcc`

will point a `/usr/local/bin/gcc` symlink to `gcc-4.9` installed by Homebrew which should override the `gcc` from `/usr/bin` if your PATH specifies `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Something to add, need to restart the shell for this one to take effect

Comment: Homebrew needs to make a stable intermediate symlink that updates with upgrades (`homebrew-gcc` or something). Then you can symlink to that and not have to manually update your symlink.

Answer (score 6):

you can use `gcc-7` instead

reference https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/40374

Answer (score 3):

When you build C/C++/Objective C etc. applications you usually do not run the C compiler from the command line you use a build system - which one of the simplest is a makefile.

The standard Unix way (e.g. from pre gcc being the only compiler) is that you pass information to the build system where your compiler is. Often this is the environment variable CC for C compiler CPP or similar for C++.

this is often done on the command line

e.g.

```
make CC=/usr/bin/clang  all # for Clang

make CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9 all # for gcc-4.9 under Homebrew
```

Answer (score 1):

[Only for m1 Mac]

Homebrew by default installs gcc to `/opt/homebrew/bin`. There you will be able to find `gcc-11`. You can also find this path by running `which gcc-11`.

You can then symlink this file to `/usr/local/bin/gcc` using this command:

```
sudo ln -s $(which gcc-11) /usr/local/bin/gcc
```

Just make sure that `/usr/local/bin` in your `$PATH` comes before `/usr/bin` to override `clang`

Comment: Ignoring for the moment that this is only valid for M1: why not just put /opt/homebrew/bin first in the PATH? And how does this solve the problem the OP has?

Comment: this answer actually coincides with my reply [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/450861/153840)

Comment: @nohillside because it doesn't link to that directory either :)

Answer (score 0):

To use Homebrew's version, you're best off creating symbolic links to the latest version of GCC installed by Homebrew, and placing them into `/usr/local/bin`.
The example `zsh` script provided below will do this for you, and will also remove the version number suffixed to the filename by Homebrew's installation formula.

```sh
# Choose the directory containing the latest version of GCC
# as indicated by the highest number suffixed to 
# the filepath of the package directory
print -v version /usr/local/opt/gcc@<->(n[-1])
version=${version#*@}
for file in /usr/local/opt/gcc@${version}/bin/*-${version}(*); do
    tail=${file:t}
    ln -sf ${file} /usr/local/bin/${tail%-*}
done
```

Now you're good to go. You can check that it worked using the command below:

```sh
gcc --version
```

**Output**

```
gcc (Homebrew GCC 10.2.0_2) 10.2.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```