# installing old version of c++ compiler

Tags: macos, xcode, gcc

I use `OSX 10.10.5` need to compile some `c++` code with an old version of `gcc`, namely `4.3.4`. I don't think `XCode` provide that kind of tools. I suppose there is a way to do that by hand. How can I do that ?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Are you going to make us guess your OS X version and the old gcc version you need?

Comment: @bmike I did not think it was `OS` specific. I have just updated my post

Comment: next time - Consider helping us help you. Take a pass at editing this after you've read the [help guide](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to be specific and show how your research didn't help you solve this dilemma.

Answer (score 1):

I have compiled older gcc in the past as a last resort.

1. [Get Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/) - it gives you clang and lots of header files. If you can't stomach it, get the command line tools.
2. Get http://brew.sh
3. `brew install gcc`

From there you can see if an older gcc is available or worst case, pull that source and compile it from the version of gcc you have running from above. It looks like you'll be able to use [homebrew](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38222/) to get at the version 4.3 from the versioned source already in the tool:

```
mac:~ me$ brew search gcc
gcc
homebrew/dupes/apple-gcc42       homebrew/versions/gcc44          homebrew/versions/gcc47          homebrew/versions/gcc5
homebrew/head-only/gccxml        homebrew/versions/gcc45          homebrew/versions/gcc48          homebrew/versions/llvm-gcc28
homebrew/versions/gcc43          homebrew/versions/gcc46          homebrew/versions/gcc49
```

Comment: I have already tried `homebrew/versions/gcc43 ` and I get this message : ` OS X Mavericks or older is required.`

Comment: @Newben Did you find the source of that message and look at the code? You could probably comment out the check and see what breaks. Or you'll need to just get the source and start fixing compile errors. That's the "last resort" I mentioned above.

Comment: ok thanks but I think it can be too complicated to fix it line after line, don't you think so ?